# CORS Issue for Cordova Application in Netbeans 8.0.2

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, netbeans, cors

I created an HTML5 Cordova Application in Netbeans 8.0.2. In that I'm trying consume a REST API from a site  webservicex.net which is providing  Currency Convertor i.e http://www.webservicex.net//CurrencyConvertor.asmx/ConversionRate?FromCurrency=USD&ToCurrency=INR.

When I'm trying to call this RESTful Webservice in my Javascript code it will  display an error message on my console like CROS Domain Problem.

This is my Code javascript code.

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#btn").click(function() {
                $.ajax({
                    url:'http://www.webservicex.net/CurrencyConvertor.asmx/ConversionRate?FromCurrency=USD&ToCurrency=INR',
                    type: 'get',
                    crossDomain: true,
                    ContentType: 'xml',
                    dataType: 'text',
                    cache: false
                    }).done(function(response) {
                    var str = response;
                    alert(str);
                    var xmlDoc = $.parseXML(str);
                    var $xml = $(xmlDoc);
                    var $Name = $xml.find('double');
                 alert(parseFloat($Name.text())+10);
                 var $a = parseFloat($Name.text())+10;
                    $('span').html($Name);
                    $("#displayout").html($a);
                }).fail(function(request, textStatus, errorThrown) {

                    alert("error, fail");

                    alert(textStatus + " : " + errorThrown.toString());
                });
            });
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that you are using the correct endpoint for the URL parameter? It seems the url you specified does not have CORS headers configured so you won't be able to access it from an external site.

Comment: The specified URL is working fine on browser and even I tried with simple http://www.google.com still its showing the same cors error.